# Defragmenting Cloud Spanner's secondary index

Tags: database, google-cloud-spanner

Spanner's secondary index does not have a reorganization command for defragmentation like a normal database.

I understand that this is not necessary as spanner compression and split splitting eliminates fragmentation.
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Correct — Spanner indices are generally automatically defragmented.

Traditional databases have the notion of a “heap file” where data is modified in place.  If for example a row is deleted, or a large string column is truncated, etc, its data is removed from the middle of the heap file, leaving behind an empty space.  Over time the file gains lots of different-sized empty spaces, leading to fragmentation.

Spanner, like most modern database engines, doesn’t have this type of heap file at all.  Instead, it uses Log-Structured Merge trees for storage.  These structures don't modify data in place.  So while they’re susceptible to other issues, they are immune to this “traditional” form of fragmentation.

You can observe Spanner’s closest equivalent of “fragmentation” as follows (just one example):  If you change a large amount of data, such as a large bulk load or a delete that removes many but not all rows, you may notice that CPU utilization remains elevated for a short while after the operation completes.  This is because Spanner bulk loads typically split data into many separate chunks, and it may be more efficient to collocate those chunks in storage (including in indices).

What you’re seeing with this briefly-elevated CPU is a background “compaction” process that automatically re-organizes the data for efficiency.  Compactions happen automatically and are usually incremental and localized to just a piece of the data.  But if you make enough changes all at once, you can see them show up in metrics.